# C++ Builder 10.2: Thread blocks WaitForInputIdle

Tags: c++, vcl

I've got the following scenario: An Application B is supposed to start an application A and then to wait for A becoming idle. For this purpose, B uses CreateProcess in combination with WaitForInputIdle, and unfortunately the timeout of this command has been set to INFINITE.

This is the corresponding part of B's source code:

```
void StartA(void){
    STARTUPINFO         siInfo;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION piInfo;

    ZeroMemory(&siInfo, sizeof(siInfo));
    ZeroMemory(&piInfo, sizeof(piInfo));

    CreateProcess(L"A.exe", L"", 0, 0, 
        false, CREATE_DEFAULT_ERROR_MODE, 0, 0,
        &siInfo, &piInfo);

    WaitForInputIdle(piInfo.hProcess, INFINITE); // A will block this command!

    CloseHandle(piInfo.hProcess);
    CloseHandle(piInfo.hThread);
}
```

When I call my application A from this application B, B will be blocked by its WaitForInputIdle command forever due to the SendMessage command invoked by A's TestThread. If I create the TestThread only after the FormShow event, then WaitForInputIdle will return as expected. That's a solution and though I'm aware of the article [WaitForInputIdle waits for any thread, which might not be the thread you care about](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100326-00/?p=14483), I like to understand what actually happens here.

This is the simplified source code of application A. It just consists out of a TForm and the class TestThread, which is derived from TThread.

```
class TestThread : public TThread {
    public:
        __fastcall TestThread(HWND in_msg) : msg(in_msg), TThread(false) {};
        virtual __fastcall ~TestThread(){};
    private:
        void __fastcall Execute(){
            // Next line leads to WaitForInputIdle blocking
            SendMessage(msg, WM_USER, NULL, NULL); 
            while(!Terminated) Sleep(1);
        }

        HWND msg;
};

class TFormA : public TForm{
    private:
        TestThread * testthread_p;
    public:
        __fastcall TFormA(TComponent* Owner){
            testthread_p = new TestThread(Handle);
        }
        virtual __fastcall ~TFormA(){}
};
```

Why does the command WaitForInputIdle fail to detect the idle state of application A?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The launched app never has a chance to enter an "input idle" state.

Assuming `TFormA` is the app's `MainForm`, it gets created at app startup, and thus creates the thread, before the VCL's main UI message loop starts running (when `Application->Run()` is called by `WinMain()`).

Even though the worker thread is using `SendMessage()` and not `PostMessage()`, it is sending messages across thread boundaries, so each message is not dispatched to the window until the receiving thread (in this case, the main UI thread) calls `(Peek|Get)Message()`.  This is stated in the [`SendMessage()` documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644950.aspx):

> Messages sent between threads are processed **only when the receiving thread executes message retrieval code**. The sending thread is blocked until the receiving thread processes the message.

By the time the main UI message loop starts running, one message from the thread has already been sent to the window and is waiting to be dispatched.  Subsequent messages are being sent with a 1ms delay between them.  So, the first time the main UI message loop attempts to retrieve a message from the queue, there is already a message waiting. By the time the loop dispatches that message for processing and goes back to the queue to wait for a message, there is already a new message waiting for it.

The [`WaitForInputIdle()` documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687022.aspx) says:

> The `WaitForInputIdle` function enables a thread to suspend its execution until the specified process has finished its initialization **and is waiting for user input with no input pending**. If the process has multiple threads, the `WaitForInputIdle` function returns as soon as **any thread becomes idle**.

The main UI thread has continuous messages pending from the thread, so it can't become "input idle". And the worker thread does not retrieve inbound messages of its own, so it can't become "input idle", either (see [WaitForInputIdle waits for any thread, which might not be the thread you care about](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100326-00/?p=14483)).

Thus, the app process as a whole never becomes "input idle", so `WaitForInputIdle()` blocks until its timeout elapses, which in this case is `INFINITE`, so it blocks indefinately.

The Form's `OnShow` event is not fired until well after the main UI message loop is running and has already processed several other window messages, so the app has time to go "input idle", unblocking `WaitForInputIdle()`, before the thread gets created and starts sending messages to the window.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! There's one thing left which I do not understand: You write that the thread sends subsequent messages with a 1 ms delay between them, but in my opinion it only sends one single message and, after this was processed, goes idle. The interval in which Sleep() is called will make no difference. So what I did expect is that the main UI message loop will process the single message it got from the thread, hence unblock the latter which then goes into idle state by calling the Sleep() function. So there should be no reason for the message queue getting crowded.

Comment: A thread becomes input idle when it attempts to retrieve a message and there is no message available. It does not become input idle when it goes to sleep. In your example. Sleep(1) is too small a time delay, the worker thread will send the next message as soon as the previous message is dispatched. So the main UI thread does not have a chance to attempt a message retrieval and see that no message is available yet. If you increase the sleep interval, the main UI thread will have more time in which it has to wait for a new message, thus it can become input idle in the meantime

Comment: Thank you for clarifying things. So in my understanding the main UI thread is busy while the worker thread is blocked by calling SendMessage() once. Afterwards the main UI thread has a chance to go input idle while the worker thread is busy (due to calling Sleep()). This explains why increasing the time period given to Sleep() does not improve the situation. I hope that I got it right. The only workaround I've found yet consists of inserting a single call to Sleep() just before calling SendMessage().

Comment: As you already said, the worker thread does not retrieve inbound messages of its own, therefore it can't become "input idle". So I just verified that calling PeekMessage() inside the worker thread does the trick, it leads to an "idle input" state of the worker thread and unblocks the external WaitForIdleInput. One last question: Does WaitForInputIdle() only survey the worker thread after its first appearance in the main UI's message loop?

Comment: @CheviN: I just now noticed that your test code is NOT looping `SendMessage()`. I misread the code initially, I though the worker thread was looping `SendMessage()`, So, everything I said earlier doesn't apply, since there is only 1 message being sent to the UI thread, and as soon as that message is done processing, the main thread should be free to go "input idle" once the UI settles down. But I tested the code and sure enough, that one call to `SendMessage()` prevents "input idle" even when the main thread is waiting for new messages. That goes against everything that Raymond Chen documents.

Comment: @CheviN: this has to be a VCL issue, not a Windows issue. Something in the VCL is likely getting triggered when the worker thread sends the message, and that something is preventing the main thread from going "input idle" correctly. When I do the same test without using the VCL at all, just straight Win32 API, the test works perfectly fine, the launched app's main thread goes "input idle" as soon as the message loop has nothing to process after the `SendMessage()`.